# Why Solidity assembly mstore(0x40, add(0x40, ....))?

Tags: solidity

ChainBridge has [a piece of solidity code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/849db5657b8ce7c340a8847078de87d3a9e421f1/contracts/handlers/ERC20Handler.sol#L155):

A:

```
assembly {

        amount := calldataload(0xC4)

        recipientAddress := mload(0x40)
        lenRecipientAddress := calldataload(0xE4)   // offset 0x20 beside amount is the length variable, I know that.
        mstore(0x40, add(0x20, add(recipientAddress, lenRecipientAddress)))  // load address to the free memory

        calldatacopy(
            recipientAddress, // copy to destinationRecipientAddress
            0xE4, // copy from calldata @ 0x104        **Why copy from 0xE4？
            sub(calldatasize(), 0xE) // copy size (calldatasize - 0x104)    
            //** Why the length is calldatasize()-0xE? Is the original comment by the author correct?
        )
    }
```

and another [piece of code](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/849db5657b8ce7c340a8847078de87d3a9e421f1/contracts/handlers/ERC721Handler.sol#L191)

B:

```
assembly {
    tokenID    := calldataload(0x64)

    destinationRecipientAddress        := mload(0x40)              // load free memory pointer
    let lenDestinationRecipientAddress := calldataload(0x84)

    let lenMeta := calldataload(add(0xA4, lenDestinationRecipientAddress))

    mstore(0x40, add(0x40, add(destinationRecipientAddress, lenDestinationRecipientAddress))) // shift free memory pointer

    calldatacopy(
        destinationRecipientAddress,                             // copy to destinationRecipientAddress
        0x84,                                                    // copy from calldata after destinationRecipientAddress length declaration @0x84
        sub(calldatasize(), add(0x84, add(0x20, lenMeta)))       // copy size (calldatasize - (0xC4 + the space metaData takes up))
    )
    // .....
```

}

The code `mstore(0x40, add(0x40, add(destinationRecipientAddress, lenDestinationRecipientAddress)))` in B, why is `add(0x40, ...)` , but in the code of A is `add(0x20, add(recipientAddress, lenRecipientAddress)`.  0x40 or 0x20 ?

Why is `0x40`? If I change to `mstore(0x40, add(0x20, add(destinationRecipientAddress, lenDestinationRecipientAddress)))`, it's also success with the test scripts.

And in GenericHandler.sol, [Line 200](https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-solidity/blob/849db5657b8ce7c340a8847078de87d3a9e421f1/contracts/handlers/GenericHandler.sol#L200)， it's `mstore(0x40, add(0x60, add(metaData, lenMeta)))`. Why is `0x60`?

Answer (score 0):

The odd numbers 0xC4 are pointer to the parameter inside `data`

```
deposit(
    bytes32 resourceID,
    uint8   destinationChainID,
    uint64  depositNonce,
    address depositer,
    bytes   calldata data
)
```

The parameters are enconded using the [contract ABI](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html). For example `data` starts at offset `0xa0`, the first 32 bytes is the length, so the data start at `0xc0`. The extra 4 is the function identifier that is required.

The `data` layout is described in the function documentation

```
    @notice Data passed into the function should be constructed as follows:
    amount                      uint256     bytes   0 - 32
    recipientAddress length     uint256     bytes  32 - 64
    recipientAddress            bytes       bytes  64 - END
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn't answer my question